# calling git diff in pre-commit shell script

Tags: git, bash, sh

I try to put the output of 'git diff' into a variable in shell script to check if file has changed, but whenn running 'git diff file' in script I always get this output:

```
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

here is what i am calling in the script

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/repo
jsdiff=`git diff file.js`
echo "jsdiff: $jsdiff"
```

any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# this script is always executed before the commit is typed
#
#

# Before commiting minify and compress javascript if changed

cd /path/to/repo/_js
jsdiff=`git diff main.js`
echo "jsdiff: $jsdiff"

#if [ "$jsdiff" != "" ]
#   then
        # compile js
#       ./googleClosureCompile.sh
#       echo "js minified"
#fi

exit 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `/path/to/file/file.js` exists? If you replace `git diff` with `ls -l`, does it work?

Comment: it does, that is not the problem, maybe the problem refers to calling an application which has to parts like `git diff`?

Comment: I just tried `apt-get install` - it worked :(

Comment: It seems that the file you are trying to diff is not in the directory with your repo.

Comment: No, that would be another error. You can get this usage message only if you are running `git diff` not inside a git repo. Are you sure you don't do `cd` or something like this before it? Show us your _whole_ `pre-commit`.

Comment: Heh. What is this `/path/to/repo`? Why do you need it?

Comment: this is my whole pre-commit file, i tried with entering the repo at the beginning, no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this error only if you run `git diff` in a directory which is not a repo, thus `git diff` thinks that you want to use it as a replacement for ordinary `diff`, so it wants two paths.

The problem here is that inside a hook `$GIT_DIR` is always set to `.git` so instead of trying to discover this directory `git` simply looks at `.git`. If you do `cd somewhere` *even inside your repo* `git` won't find this `.git` directory and it will think that it is not in a repo. So the easiest you can do is just avoid using `cd` in hooks.

Instead of

```
cd /path/to/repo/_js
jsdiff=`git diff main.js`
```

do just

```
jsdiff=`git diff _js/main.js`
```

---

Also it's better to check `git diff` exit code. Here is how to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

git diff --quiet _js/main.js || {
    # compile js
    # ...
}
```

Comment: @quidage Also It would be better to add `--exit-code` argument to your `git diff` command and check for exit code instead of output.

Comment: @quidage Please, have a look at my answer, I've updated it a bit.

Comment: it worked best for me when i added the revision
`git diff --exit-code origin -- _js/main.js > /dev/null || { ... }`

Comment: @quidage Why don't you use `--quite`? It implies `--exit-code` and won't output anything, so you won't have to add `> /dev/null`. I don't know why you had to add `origin`, that's strange as by default it will compare with the currently checked out branch. Anyway, using `master` instead of `origin` is probably a better idea.

Comment: Referring your last comment I think this should be a good solution to diff against HEAD:
`git diff --quiet HEAD~1 -- _js/main.js || {}`
Do you agree?

Comment: @quidage to `diff` _against HEAD_ you should use `HEAD` in your command; `HEAD~1` diffs against HEAD's parent which is not you want, since your commit is not yet commited in pre-commit hook.